# How to find a variable by name in tensorflow2.0

Tags: tensorflow2.0

It seems that tensorflow 2.0 has removed the function tf.global_variables(). My question is then: how do I find a variable with given name in a model? Does tensorflow 2.0 provide a function to do this?

Currently, our training framework does not have access to code that builds models. It uses tf.global_variables() to find various variables in a loaded model to push-in and pull-out training data or results. Would tensorflow 2.0 be able to support this kind of framework?

Comment: perhaps this is what are looking for: https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/keras/functional#extracting_and_reusing_nodes_in_the_graph_of_layers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would tensorflow 2.0 be able to support this kind of framework?

No, it won't.

One of the first design choices of Tensorflow 2.0 was the complete removal of the global collections (e.g. `tf.global_variables()`) in favour of a Python-centric approach of using Python objects that carry their own variables.

The recommended practice is now to build a Keras model and use the same model everywhere in the code, by using the Python object.
You can access the trainable and non-trainable variables of the object by accessing `model.trainable_variables` and `model.non_trainable_weights`.

In short, you have to start migrating your code base to an Object Oriented approach, since the 1.x approach of tensorflow (that relies upon global collections, getting variables by name, and so on) won't be available in 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This is the kind of radical change at low level API we have not expected.

Comment: There is no hurry to start using TF2 though. You can use TF1 for a long time (although it would be better to migrate the codebase to TF2 - it requires some refactor work but in the long term it is worth it).

Btw if my answer clarified your doubts, please consider marking it as accepted. Thanks!