# How to reuse variables in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

When using tensorflow 2.0, I find something weird about tf.Variable? There are two cases bellow.

The first one

```
x1 = tf.Variable(12., name='x')
x2 = tf.Variable(12., name='x')
print(x1 is x2)
x1.assign(1.)
print(x1)
print(x2)
```

The output is

```
False
<tf.Variable 'x:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=1.0>
<tf.Variable 'x:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=12.0>
```

which means variables with the same name don't share the same memory.

The second one

```
x = tf.Variable(12., name='x')
print(x)
y = x.assign(5.)
print(y)
print(x is y)

x.assign(3.)
print(x)
print(y)
```

The output is

```
<tf.Variable 'x:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=12.0>
<tf.Variable 'UnreadVariable' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=5.0>
False
<tf.Variable 'x:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=3.0>
<tf.Variable 'UnreadVariable' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=3.0>
```

The result is unexpected, variables `x` and `y` with different names share the same memory, but `id(x)` is not equal to `id(y)`.

Therefore, the name of variable can't distinguish whether variables are identical(share the same memory). And how can I reuse variables in tensorflow 2.0, like `with tf.variable_scope("scope", reuse=True) tf.get_variable(...)` in tensorflow 1.0?

Comment: Do you have a concrete example on how you would like to reuse variables?

Comment: For example, the variable `x` is defined in the net A, I want to create the net B to reuse `x`.

Comment: What is stopping you from directly using `A.x` in `B`? Maybe something like this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56201185/how-to-find-a-variable-by-name-in-tensorflow2-0

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from your question:

> The result is unexpected, variables x and y with different names share the same memory, but id(x) is not equal to id(y).

No, this is incorrect. From the docs of [`tf.Variable.assign`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#assign), where `read_value` is default to `True`:

> read_value: if True, will return **something** which evaluates to the new value of the variable; if False will return the assign op.

Here "something" should be a new operation, which isn't `x`, but is evaluated to the value of `x`.

To reuse `x`, just access `x`:

```
y = x
print(y is x) # True
```

Finally, regarding:

> which means variables with the same name don't share the same memory.

> Therefore, the name of variable can't distinguish whether [...]

You have to create different(thus distinguishable) `name`s yourself, regarding your first example. You might want to take a look at the comments of this accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73024334/5290519