# The `trainable_variables` of tf.keras.layers.Layer still include those of tf.Module when guide says don't mix the two?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

As title. Now I'm reading this guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_modules.
There is a quote on the page: (bold text by me)

> Note: tf.Module is the base class for both tf.keras.layers.Layer and tf.keras.Model, so everything you come across here also applies in Keras. For historical compatibility reasons **Keras layers do not collect variables from modules**, so your models should use only modules or only Keras layers. However, the methods shown below for inspecting variables are the same in either case.

But I tried this hierarchy: `tf.Module` with nested `tf.keras.layers.Layer`, which has nested `tf.Module`. And I got all `tf.Variable`s from `model.trainable_variables`. So it seems that the note above is wrong?

These are the code I used in the testing:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
keras = tf.keras
from keras import layers

class Dense(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features, out_features, name=None):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        
        with self.name_scope:
            self.w = tf.Variable(
                    tf.random.normal([in_features, out_features], name='w'))
            self.b = tf.Variable(
                    tf.zeros([out_features], name='b'))

    def __call__(self, x):
        y = tf.matmul(x, self.w) + self.b
        return tf.nn.relu(y)

class KDense(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, in_features, out_features, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.W = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([in_features, out_features]), name='kd_W')
        self.b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([out_features]), name='kd_b')

    def call(self, x):
        y = tf.matmul(x, self.W) + self.b
        return tf.nn.relu(y)


class MLP(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features, layer_sizes, name=None):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.layers = []
        with self.name_scope:
            for size in layer_sizes:
                self.layers.append(KDense(in_features=in_features, out_features=size, name='d'))
                in_features = size
        
    def __call__(self, x):
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = layer(x)
        return x


mod = MLP(in_features=5, layer_sizes=[5, 5], name='mlp')
for idx, v in enumerate(mod.trainable_variables):
    print(idx, v.name, v.shape)
```

and the output is like:

```
0 mlp/kd_W:0 (5, 5)
1 mlp/kd_b:0 (5,)
2 mlp/dense/b:0 (5,)
3 mlp/dense/w:0 (5, 5)
4 mlp/kd_W:0 (5, 5)
5 mlp/kd_b:0 (5,)
6 mlp/dense/b:0 (5,)
7 mlp/dense/w:0 (5, 5)
```

But I expect those `tf.Variable`s from `mlp/dense/...` would not be printed.

---

Update:

The same page, section: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_modules#keras_models

also has a note saying the same thing:

> Note: To emphasize the note above, a raw tf.Module nested inside a Keras layer or model will not get its variables collected for training or saving. Instead, nest Keras layers inside of Keras layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems like already fixed -so you could use as mixture -, but the documentation hasn't been corrected.
You could check this issue how things going on
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47264

Comment: Thanks :) I did leave a comment there three weeks ago but it seems that they don't have time to reply.